# Yahoo finance exchange rates not fetching data for current date

Tags: xml, api, yahoo, finance, yql

I am trying to fetch the exchange rates using following query:

```
    http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDNPR%22,%20%22EURNPR%22,%20%22AUDNPR%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

and the result is:

```
<results>
<rate id="USDNPR">
<Name>USD/NPR</Name>
<Rate>108.6000</Rate>
<Date>1/20/2017</Date>
<Time>10:00am</Time>
<Ask>109.2000</Ask>
<Bid>108.6000</Bid>
</rate>
<rate id="EURNPR">
<Name>EUR/NPR</Name>
<Rate>115.8600</Rate>
<Date>1/20/2017</Date>
<Time>10:30am</Time>
<Ask>115.8900</Ask>
<Bid>115.8600</Bid>
</rate>
<rate id="AUDNPR">
<Name>AUD/NPR</Name>
<Rate>83.7963</Rate>
<Date>3/17/2017</Date>
<Time>11:10pm</Time>
<Ask>84.2593</Ask>
<Bid>83.7963</Bid>
</rate>
</results>
```

The problem is the result is shown from the historical data i.e. of dates 1/20/2017 and 3/17/2017. I want the result to be shown for the most recent date and time. I suppose there is a bug in the Yahoo API to show the historical data randomly. Is there any solution to this. Help appreciated.

Comment: Possibly because 3/17 is a Friday, most current business day, it runs until then.

Comment: I do not think so. In addition, 1/20 is a long way back.